# Using self written functions across different directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function_timer() to time the runtime of programs and I want to use the function when writing code across different directories when working on other programs. How do I make it such that importing the function is simplified across different directories?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to create a python module. A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py

create timer.py then write the following function as its content:

```
def mytimer():
   #your timer code here
```

Then you can import hello as long as the file location is accessible from where the calling program is working

```
import timer

timer.mytimer()
```

To group many .py files put them in a folder. Any folder with an **init**.py is considered a module by python and you can call them a package

```
|-TimerModule
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ timer.py
```